# R error: Wrong length for a vector, should be 2 while using Geosphere package

Tags: r, dataframe, haversine, geosphere, rowwise

I am trying to analyze avg distance between two locations to come with an acceptable cutoff for auto approval of traveled distance.
I have tied referring to ([geosphere distHaversine() & dplyr - error wrong length for vector, should be 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554592/geosphere-disthaversine-dplyr-error-wrong-length-for-vector-should-be-2)) & ([Getting Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209267/getting-error-in-pointstomatrixp1-wrong-length-for-a-vector-should-be-2)) but I am unable to debug the error and complete my analysis.

Data frame is something like this with 10 rows of data.

```
df <- c(lat1,long1,lat2,long2)
```

[df matrix with 10 rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L483W.png)

when I try to use the following

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(HVRSINE = distHaversine(c(df$long1,df$lat1),c(df$long2,df$lat2)))
```

the error comes as:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `HVRSINE`.
x Wrong length for a vector, should be 2

The error occurred in row 1.
```

when i manually write lat,long for in the disthaversine, the output works like a charm.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `$` in `dplyr` commands. `df$long1` overrides `dplyr`'s non-standard evaluation to specifically pull the entire `long1` column from the whole `df`, ignoring the `rowwise` and any `group_by`, and any other fancy `dplyr` stuff. Change to `mutate(HVRSINE = distHaversine(c(long1, lat1), c(long2, lat2)))` and I think it should work.

Comment: if you want an answer based on your sampledata, please edit your post with the output of (something like) `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(HVRSINE = unlist(pmap(list(a = long1, 
                                    b = lat1, 
                                    x = long2,
                                    y = lat2),
                               ~ distHaversine(c(..1, ..2), c(..3, ..4)))))
```